# Schauder basis in a non-normable space

Tags: vector-spaces, banach-spaces, schauder-basis

I want to better understand what characterize the vector spaces that have a Schauder basis.

Usually such a basis  $ \{u_i \} \quad i\in \mathbb{N}$ is defined for a Banach space using the norm to define the convergence of the series that gives any vector  $v$ of the space as:$$v=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i u_i $$

My question is if we can define such a countable basis also in a topological vector space that is not normable, so that it is not a Banach space. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis#Definitions) it seems that this is possible using the convergence of sequences in the given topology, but I don't see how this can be concretely  done. As an example: what is a Schauder basis for  the space of distributions, that ( it seems to me) is a non-normable vector space ? Or for other similar spaces.

---

Added to clarify my problem.

What is strange for me is that, if a Schauder basis exists, such that $$v=\sum_{i=0}^\infty v_i u_i \qquad w=\sum_{i=0}^\infty w_i u_i $$ than we can define an inner product in the vector space as
$$
\langle v,w\rangle=\sum_{i=0}^\infty v_i w_i
$$
and, from this inner product, we have a norm... so the space is normable (contradiction or my mistake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a topological vector space with a Schauder basis, you can attempt to define an inner product $\langle v,w\rangle=\sum_{i=0}^\infty v_i w_i$ as you have done.  However, the sum defining this inner product may fail to converge.  And even if it does converge, the inner product may induce a different topology than the given topology.  So the mere existence of a Schauder basis certainly doesn't mean that the topology on your space must come from an inner product.

As a simple example of a Schauder basis in a non-normable space, consider the space $\ell^p$ for $1\leq p<\infty$ equipped with the weak topology (not the usual norm topology!).  The sequences which have all entries $0$ except for a single $1$ form a Schauder basis.

Comment: Thank you! There is some example of a Schauder basis that gives an inner product that induce a different topology? And is it know a Schauder basis for the space of distributions?

Comment: In the examples I gave the inner product induces a different topology (and the inner product always converges if $p\leq 2$).  I don't know of a Schauder basis for distributions.